# Drive API to get Documents, Spreadsheets,Presentations alone?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to get documents/spreadsheets/presentations alone from drive.I used search query q parameter to get documents based on mimeType, but using this I can able to get only one particular mimetype files.Drive supports two mimetypes for spreadsheets

1.application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
2.application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet

There is no **or** operator to form a query.Can anyone help me to get a solution for this?

Comment: Google spreadsheets have a mime type of application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet

Comment: Ya, using this mimetype I can get only spreadsheets which are created using Google Drive not uploaded spreadsheets has other mimetype.

Comment: well it depends on whether you upload with convert=true or convert=false

Comment: I want both converted and unconverted spreadsheets (mimetypes application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet and application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet) from Drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `OR` operator. Use `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet' or mimeType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'` to query your files.

Comment: Thanks it's working fine.In the below link they didn't mentioned about OR operator https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters